# What's the difference between Amazon's EC2 and S3 services?

Tags: amazon-s3

I heard Amazon is going to offer a free trail of their hosting services soon with their EC2 tier. I'm a new web developer and I'm still learning a lot about hosting and server configuration so I'm looking at a lot of hosts.
What are some main differences between EC2 and S3 services offered by Amazon?

Comment: EC2-we can install whatever software we want
S3-for data storage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EC2 = Elastic Cloud Computing

S3 = Simple Storage Service

One is for application hosting, one is for data storage.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 offer storage service. where you can read, write and access your data via REST/SOAP from Cloud.

EC2 offers renting of virtual computers(like how we use our vmware,xenservers), you can create/delete/modify your instances.